# Multihop ping6 in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, networking, ping, p2p

I would like to ping a node through a multi hop route using ping6. Let's say I have interfaces A, B, and C and they are connected to each other via p2p connection. The connection orientation is like this B-A-C (like A is in the middle and connected to both B and C, and A is the Group Owner)I would like to ping C from B as the following: B->A->C. If I wanted to ping using a single hop I would use `ping6 -I <interface name of source> <Inet6 address of destination>`. I was wondering if it's possible to ping over multi hop. Please help!

Comment: @WooJoo You should convert that comment to an answer...  **;-)**\

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terminal program traceroute for the this task.

Your specific case would look for example like this:

`traceroute -6 -i "B-interface" -g "A-IP" "C-IP"`

here the `-6` flag stands for IPv6

`-i` for the outgoing interface on your host

`-g` for gateway or as the next hop in your case

and finaly your destination

if your connection was the default route you could also use just tracepath6 with the IP of the destination and it would do the work for you.